# Cargo recompiles all dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I think the reason is rust-analyzer extension in VS Code. It does cargo check after saving. And it checks my dependencies too, what is stupid. If i turn it off cargo will build correctly. How can i prevent cargo checking and compiling my dependencies?

Ok, i just changed workspace in vs code and the problem solved itself.

Comment: The check is only performed once on your dependencies unless they are changed or the cache was cleared (by either deleting the `target` folder or running `cargo clean`).

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it off in Settings "rust-analyzer".

`rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.command`

Comment: But it will turn off checking globaly and i need it to not check dependencies. Thanks  for response anyway